# Natural join vs inner join giving different number of rows for a simple query in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join, cross-join

I've been under the impression from my class and googling that the only difference between an inner join and a natural join is that a natural join only returns one copy of the column you're joining on, whereas an inner join returns both. So I was surprised to discover in the following (simplified) example that a natural join returns 2 rows (which seems correct to me), whereas an inner join returns 4 (which seems wrong).

Simplified example:

```
/* Delete the tables if they already exist */
drop table if exists Movie;
drop table if exists Reviewer;
drop table if exists Rating;

/* Create the schema for our tables */
create table Movie(shared1 int, unshared2 text);
create table Rating(shared1 int, unshared3 int);

insert into Movie values(1, 'a');
insert into Movie values(2, 'b');
insert into Rating values(1,3);
insert into Rating values(1,3);
```

then the sql results...

```
sqlite> select * from Movie natural join Rating;
1|a|3
1|a|3

/*seems correct*/

sqlite> select * from Movie inner join Rating;
1|a|1|3
1|a|1|3
2|b|1|3
2|b|1|3

/*seems strange and/or wrong*/

sqlite> select * from Movie inner join Rating on Movie.shared1 = Rating.shared1;
1|a|1|3
1|a|1|3

/*seems right*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this query:

```
select * from Movie inner join Rating
```

you use `INNER JOIN` without an `ON` clause.

This is equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select * from Movie cross join Rating
```

Typically an `INNER JOIN` should have an `ON` clause but in SQLite it can be omitted.

From [Determination of input data (FROM clause processing)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#determination_of_input_data_from_clause_processing_):

> If the join-operator is "CROSS JOIN", "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" or a comma
> (",") and there is no ON or USING clause, then the result of the join
> is simply the cartesian product of the left and right-hand datasets.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c14ef733f9751174a975696169d3f991).